# Issue with creating a New-Object -ComObject in a process called powershell script on single PC

Tags: powershell

A simplified version of what I have, is three powershell scripts.  One calls other powershell scripts using credentials.  The second calls a function which is stored in the third script.  So basically the main function of my first script looks something like this:

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($script,$param) &$script $param} -ArgumentList $scriptToRun,$param) -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred`

This function succesfully calls the second script, which takes the passed in parameter like this:

`param($path) . ./functions.ps1 addToiTunes $path`

The third script contains a function called addToiTunes which basic function starts by creating a COM object for iTunes like this:

`function addToiTunes($path) { 
  $iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.application
  Write-Host "Completed"
}`

The problem is, it never gets to the Write-Host statement.  It just hangs there on the New-Object statement, then eventually stops and states that "script execution complete'.

Any idea why this would be occurring?  Is it because it's trying to create a new com object in a background process?  Or could it be my credentials call isn't actually working?

Does anyone know of a better way to call the New-Object?  Or should I be checking for an existing object of that application?  I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: BTW, it's definitely calling the function, because if I add a Write-Host statement to before the New-Object statement it will print it.

Comment: My other query, is whether it could be a permissions thing to do with Powershell itself?

Comment: Saying a "remote" powershell script is probably not accurate since they are all running on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be something to do with the credentials. If i remove the computername and creds from the call, I don't get the CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE message, which is all well and good when the credentials are not required...

**UPDATE**
I've created a new Question which is more directly related to the issue here: [Using credentials on ScriptBlock causing COM errors connecting to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416141/using-credentials-on-scriptblock-causing-com-errors-connecting-to-application)

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the famous old second hop issue with Powershell? you need to set up client credential delegation with **Enable-WSManCredSSP**, see the Scripting guy here:http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx

Otherwise the second 'n third powershell script does not inherit your credentials and runs as local system.

Comment: Is this also true if all three scripts are running on the same machine?  Because I'm not sure I can set the Enable-WSManCredSSP -role Server & Enable-WSManCredSSP -role Client -delegate BLAH on the one PC?

Comment: After attempting to set up the above, and have run: `winrm set winrm/config/service '@{CertificateThumbprint="<thumbprint>"}'` I got the following error message: `New-PSSession : [<PCNAME>] Connecting to remote server <PCNAME> failed with the following error message : The WinRM client received an HTTP server error status (500), but the remote service did not include any other 
information about the cause of the failure.`

Comment: for referece: `WinRM Quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.`

Comment: If it's of any use, this is the error I'm getting: 

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {DC0C2640-1415-4644-875C-6F4D769839BA} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 
(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand